# How to download ATG 11.0 in ubuntu system?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, software-sources, oracle, download-manager

I'm trying to download ATG 11.0 in my ubuntu system (version **18.04**) from this site - [This Link](https://edelivery.oracle.com/osdc/faces/SoftwareDelivery#!) but the download option is not getting enabled instead its showing - "The Download manager is not compatible with your environment".

I've shared the screenshot below.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "The Download manager is not compatible with your environment" is an issue with that website. They decide what is compatible so you will need to ask them why it isn't allowed to download with Ubuntu 18.04. The link you post is useless without making an account. I would suggest clicking the "wget options". I'd assume that will get you a command line method for downloading

Comment: No wget options also was not of any help. I clicked on the zip files and downloading manually. that's the only option.